# prettier convert multi line to single line in constructor function

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I use prettier for formatting code. Recently I followed that sometimes it's pretty annoying. It's auto create multi line to single line in constructor function. How can I stop this behavior?

## Before Save

[image: Before Save]

## After Save

[image: After Save]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a `,` after the end of line in `line 33`.

That's how prettier or any common formatter works, if you add a comma after a line that needs comma then it would come to the next line, else it will make it inline like yours.

Answer (score 3):

You're having a typo.

On line 30 through 33 you're ending lines with `,`. These should be semicolons `;`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to do this config** --> Extentions-->prettier --->Settings

there's a check box ticked under Prettier: 'Require Config'. If that's unchecked it will break your lines automatically[image]